# Why does the variance of the sampling distribution of the statistic do not disapear when sampling the whole population?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem

This might sound a stupid question but it is indeed a real one.

I'm trying to figure a Confidence interval for the average age of my population.

Given i have a population of 100 individual, and i sample 3 of them. From CLT, i can say that $Var[\bar{x}_3] = \frac{s^2}{3} $. Alright.

I want to increase precision of my confidence interval and thus i sample more. I head toward a 100 individual sample.

From CLT, i can say that $Var[\bar{x}_{100}] = \frac{s^2}{100} $, which clearly is not zero. Small but not Zero.

Where did i do something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sampling in an i.i.d. fashion, i.e. with replacement. A sample of size 100 does not necessarily include all 100 individuals; most likely, it will not (you have both people sampled several times and people that are not sampled). So you still have uncertainty, and variance in your estimator.

In short: if you get independent samples (which matters to apply the statistical results you are using) you are **not** (necessarily) sampling the whole population.

Comment: I understand : thank you for this niance that brings clarification. This is how my problem is different: i sample without replacement. How does that affect the variance?

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/woreplshort.htm), it may (?) help.

Answer (score 1):

You are sampling from a finite population so you samples are not in fact independent - once you sampled a person, they are out and you are sampling from a smaller pool of people. Once your sample size gets compatible (order of magnitude) with population size, these effects start to matter more and more.

Comment: Thank you. It makes more sense now with that clarification. Is there a critical number (or ratio) of sample vs population to never cross and what are the tool to find the variance of a highly sampled (w/o replacement) population?

Comment: @Masta The link given above has all the necessary formulas and discussion in the bottom. A rule of thumb is that the sample size should be an order of magnitude (a.k.a. $10$ times) smaller than population size before you need to introduce corrections to "with replacement" formulas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!